# How to reencode stream in fly and translate?

Tags: stream, shoutcast, icecast, internet-radio

I have urls to the Icecast/Shoutcast streams, how can i relay these streams in multiple bitrates? I know how to reencode file, but don't know how to reencode stream in multiple bitrates.

```
For example i find two icecast/shoutcast stream url/server:

http://icecast_stream.ru:8000/play
http://shoutcast_stream:8000/

I want to relay it in multiple bitrates:
http://localhost:8000/icecast_stream_32
http://localhost:8000/icecast_stream_64
http://localhost:8000/icecast_stream_128


http://localhost:8000/shoutcast_stream_32
http://localhost:8000/shoutcast_stream_64
http://localhost:8000/shoutcast_stream_128
```

Can I do it with Icecast + Ices or which soft i need to use?

Comment: I strongly suggest getting these streams from the source encoder.  When you re-compress already lossy-compressed audio, you lose even more quality and artifacts start to become more audible.  By going to the source, you only lose quality once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream transcoding can be done with multiple tools. avconv/ffmpeg, vlc, liquidsoap, ezstream, … 
One example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29500982/2648865

Towards your multiple bitrate part: you need to run multiple processes of the transcoding tool in most cases. 
If you are concerned with bandwidth consumption, then I'd recommend to set up a relay of the remote stream on your local Icecast server and use that as the input for the transcoding.

*added after question was edited:*
I'm going to guess that both original streams are 128k.
As explained here: http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/relaying.html#setting-up-a-single-broadcast-relay

`<relay>
    <server>icecast_stream.ru</server>
    <port>8000</port>
    <mount>/play</mount>
    <local-mount>/icecast_stream_128</local-mount>
    <relay-shoutcast-metadata>1</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>`

To obtain the two lower quality streams, proceed as outlined above. It's complicated using ices for this, so one of the others would be easier.
If you want to automate starting the transcoding, look into:
http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#mountsettings - specifically on-connect:
`<mount>
    <mount-name>/icecast_stream_128</mount-name>
    <on-connect>/usr/local/bin/start-transcoders-icecast-stream</on-connect>
</mount>`
*note:* this command is run before the stream is available, you might need to delay startup of the transcoders by a few seconds to avoid problems.

Comment: Ices also can or not?
Can U show a example for IceS or EzStream?
For example: http://ip:port/some_mount -- icecast stream url. I need keys moments how to retranslate it in localhost(for example) in 64 and 128 bitrate

Comment: As you clarified your question I was able to provide some example. As said there, ices is not ideal. EZ-stream, avconv or liquidsoap would be better suited. Liquidsoap, while complicated to set up, would probably be able to do everything in one, even without the local relay.

Comment: can U recommend a stream transcoder and write how to use it?

Comment: I pointed out an example at the very beginning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499768/how-can-i-decode-an-mp3-and-encode-it-as-aac-with-ezstream/29500982#29500982 What about it is unclear?

Comment: but i need ices0 or ffmpeg example how to do it, can U help?

Comment: ffmpeg -re -i http://someserver/stream.mp3 -c:a opus -b:a 20k \
           -application audio -vbr on -frame_duration 60 \
           -content_type audio/ogg \
           icecast://source:bar@server:8000/test-20.opus
 Notice how I just replaced 'avconv' with 'ffmpeg', as those are interchangeable.